# System.Data.DataTable missing all properties and methods

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017

I'm writing a .NET Standard DAL and I'm trying to use System.Data.DataTable, but it's missing all its methods and properties (when I look at it in the Object Browser, its page is blank!)  The default constructor is missing and the Load() method is missing.

My project is targeting .NET Standard 1.4.

I installed System.Data.Common(4.3.0) and System.Data.SqlClient(4.4.0) with NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

According to this, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/12426, if I'm reading this right, it's missing until .NET Standard 1.7.

**Edit:** No, no, no, I got this all wrong.  The problem was that I didn't have ".NET Core cross-platform development" selected when I installed Visual Studio 2017.  That gave me the class library project template that targets .NET Frameworks.  That seems like a bug to me because the "ASP.NET and web development" item says it includes ".NET Framework 4.6.1 development tools", but I guess it doesn't include all of them or something.  I'm quite possibly very confused about this whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to either include the namespace at the top of the program trying to use the DataTable, or you need to fully qualify the name of the class, everytime you reference it. e.g.

```
using System.Data;

System.Data.DataTable myTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

Comment: Yeah, I have the using statement.  The type is there, it just doesn't have any properties or methods but the ones derived from object.  I think it's just incomplete.

Comment: Yeah, they put an empty class in there: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8622